# How to Fix or deal with Dynamic Paginated Urls in Classified Website

Tags: seo, pagination

We have a classified website where we have different categories like male clothes, female clothes etc

Following are the url structure of the paginated pages:

```
https://in.mywebsite.com/female-clothes?page=1  
https://in.mywebsite.com/female-clothes?page=2 and so on
```

We have canonical included as self canonical tags in the following manner:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://in.mywebsite.com/female-clothes?page=1">

<link rel="canonical" href="https://in.mywebsite.com/female-clothes?page=2">
```

We have done one more thing in search console i.e we have mentioned URL Parameters in following way:

```
Parameter: Page  
Effects: Paginates  
Crawl: Let Googlebot decide
```

I just want to ask whether we have done everything correctly to handle the pagination in our website.

Please let me know if anything is done wrong and also the best way to handle the pagination issue.

Thanks

Comment: Are you experiencing any issues? Or are you just asking for a good review?

Comment: No, I am not here for good reviews, I am genuinely asking, I also want to ask how to know if pagination is hurting your seo, how to find it.  I am asking because we aren't getting any satisfactory improvement in our rankings.